# Rotating a table in a .tex file

Tags: rotating, external-files

I have a `.tex` file and I am trying to rotate it. I won't post the whole thing, but it's a table file:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
%insert content here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to input this table to another file using: `\input{../folder/name.tex}`

I've tried the following:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\input{../folder/name.tex}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

This creates a blank page, but nothing.

I also tried these two options:

```
\rotatebox{90}{\input{../folder/name.tex}}
```

```
\begin{rotate}
\input{../folder/name.tex}
\end{rotate}
```

This time, I did not see a placeholder blank page.

The first two both give me the error "Not in outer par mode", and the third gave me a "Missing number, treated as zero." All compiled.

I think the main problem is that I need `\begin{table}`, then `\begin{sidewaystable}` (or whatever), and then `\begin{tabular}`. However, I would prefer not to do this as it would mean editing that `.tex` file.

Does anyone have an idea? I've searched around but haven't been able to find the answers.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that the included file contains the *whole* float object, environment `table`. Float objects cannot be nested or put into other boxes, therefore all the variants `sidewaystable`, `\rotatebox` and `rotating` will not work.

Either you can replace `table` by `sidewaystable` and input the file as whole float object. The following example puts only the naked table (environment `tabular`) into the external file to show that all variants work:

```
% The external file in this example is generated by filecontents
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{table-example.tex}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Hello & World\\
  foo & bar\\
\end{tabular}% remove white space by line end
\end{filecontents}

% Document
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \input{table-example}
    \caption{Sidewaystable}
  \end{sidewaystable}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \fbox{%
      \rotatebox{90}{\input{table-example}\unskip}%
    }
    \caption{Rotatebox}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \fbox{%
      \begin{rotate}{90}
        \input{table-example}\unskip
      \end{rotate}%
    }
    \caption{Rotate}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX, the external file contains:

```
%% LaTeX2e file `table-example.tex'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `test' on 2015/04/13.
%%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Hello & World\\
  foo & bar\\
\end{tabular}% remove white space by line end
```

Result:

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]

**Remarks:**

- I have added `\unskip` after `\input{table-example}` to remove the last white space after the table, for the case, `\end{tabular}` does not remove the line end by an immediately following comment: `\end{tabular}%`.
- `\fbox` shows, that `rotate` does not leave any space for the table, from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/rotating/rotating.pdf) of package `rotating`:

  > `rotate`
  >   prints the contents turned through an arbitrary angle but does not leave
  >   any space for the result

Answer (score 0):

Unless you mean something quite different, this works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% here we write the sideways table to an external file just for the sake of the example.
\begin{filecontents}{sidetab.tex}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{tabular}{p{9cm}p{9cm}}

    \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[1] \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\usepackage{rotating,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\input{sidetab}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```